# Tracking specific text with MLKit

Tags: ocr, google-mlkit

Suppose that I detect a text of interest from a video feed (e.g., the temperature in a video of a thermostat). Is there a way to track this number if, for example, the camera tilts or pans and the number is in a different position in the frame?

MLKit is only able to track a few objects by default, so wondering what would I need to do to track the numbers in this case.

Comment: Have you checked ML Kit's Text Recognition SDK? https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2

Comment: That recognizes text, but doesn't track it. What I want is something like https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/box_tracking.html but that is able to follow a specific number it has detected.

Comment: I'm afraid ML Kit doesn't support this tracking for OCR.